# Delay the jQuery animation

Tags: jquery

How do I delay the jQuery animation on my page until all CSS images are loaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/window.onload) event instead of `document.ready` via [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/), like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  //animate things
});
```

The main difference here is that images are loaded, where they may or may not be on `ready`, since it's looking to see that the DOM is loaded, not necessarily extra content in it, like images.

Answer (score 2):

use the `onload` event.

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
   // do the animation
});
```